# Props are showing empty value above `render` function while it work inside `render` function?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-props

So I am passing props from `app.js` to `state.jsx` but while console logging the props it give me a `undefined` but it perfectly works inside the `render` function. Why that's happening?

**App.js**

```
class App extends React.Component{

  state = {
    data : {},
    states: '',
}

async componentDidMount () {
    const  dataFromApi = await StateData();
    this.setState({ data: dataFromApi})
}

handleStateChange = async(states) => {
    const  fetchedData = await StateData(states);
    
    this.setState({data: fetchedData, states: states})
    
}
  render(){
    const {data, states} = this.state;
    console.log(data);
    return (
      <div className="App">
        <StateCard data={data} states={states}/>
      </div>
    );
  }
}
```

**State.jsx**

```
export default class StateCard extends React.Component{

        constructor(props) {
//this doesn't work
          super(props)
          const dta = this.props.data.confirmed
          console.log(dta)
         
        }

        // spacing deafult value is 8px , so the 3*8=24px width column

        render(){

//This works
          console.log(this.props.data.confirmed)
          console.log(this.props.states)
          const {confirmed,active, deaths, recovered} = this.props.data
           return (
            <div>
             <span>Confirmed : {confirmed}</span>
            </div>);}
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you can use useEffect and Function component instead of React.Component.
it's more easier then using componentdidMount and other lifecycle methods.

```
import React, { useEffect } from "react";

const StateCard = props => {
  const { data, states } = props;
  const { confirmed, active, deaths, recovered } = data;

  useEffect(() => {
    console.log(confirmed);
    console.log(states);
  }, [props]);

  return (
    <div>
      <span>Confirmed : {confirmed}</span>
    </div>
  );
};

export default StateCard;
```